# Display a toast in Async

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I am trying to display a toast if the link that provided in "EditText" is equal to a specific link.
Else the code keep runing until result.

Thats how I tried to do(Its not detecting the link):

```
    if (urls[0].equals ("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=null&appid=8e19904c6a1db15924eef5084a978de7"))
    {
        Log.e("Test","Error!");
    }
```

My main code,if you need anything else from the code just tell me and I will upload:

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(final String... urls) {

    Log.e("URL", "Loading url = " + urls[0]);


    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    if (urls[0].equals ("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=null&appid=8e19904c6a1db15924eef5084a978de7"))
    {
        Log.e("Test","DSADSADASDASDAS");
    }

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        url = new URL(urls[0]);
        urlConnection =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line;


        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return result.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        result.append("Error: MalformedURLException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result.toString();
}


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

        Log.e("JSON data",""+weatherInfo);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mCityName +" has been loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

        for(int i = 0; 0 < jArray.length(); i++){


         JSONObject partJson = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         mMain.setText("The Weather in " + mCityName + " is: " + partJson.getString("main"));
         mDescription.setText("And " + partJson.getString("description"));
         mMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         mDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a `Toast` from a background thread you need to call it inside `runOnUIThread` like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "URL is the same", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

This is assuming your `AsincTask` is inside an activity class.

`runOnUIThread` is a method of `Activity` class, and you need a `Context` to show the `Toast`.

If your `AsyncTask` is in a separate class, you will need to provide an `Activity` as a parameter, or use an `Intent` to communicate with an `Activity`.